# IRS A2A - Using AATS once in production for logic testing

Tags: irs

In the past (2017) we have completed the required AATS testing scenarios and completed them successfully.  The IRS has subsequently moved our TCC to production and have been filing in 2017 and 18 without issue.

My company is in the process of rebuilding its SOAP application and would like to run a number of test scenarios of our own to help validate some logic as well as a few edge cases – Are we able to send data to AATS (using IRS name controls) to read the IRS responses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to still transmit over the AATS service, you'll just need to switch over the required pieces of information like the endpoint and TCC. I still occasionally use AATS on my local copy of our service to test any issues that people bring up.